# Do derivatives of every function at a branch point eventually become infinite?

Tags: derivatives, branch-points

Every function I've come up with, which has a [branch point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point), e.g. $x^\beta(\ln x)^\gamma$ at $x=0$, after several repeated differentiations appear to have an infinite limit at the branch point — at least from some side. I guess it's a common property of branch points that eventually their derivatives become infinite, given a high enough order of the derivative.

Is this correct in general? Or are there any other types of branch points, derivatives of which always remain finite?

Comment: Please define a branch point in this context.

Comment: @zhw. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: If you have a jump in the value of derivative, you would eventually end up with the infinity. Sounds logical